# Outlook Query to highlight messages that mention me?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, regex, microsoft-outlook-2013, conditional-formatting

In essence, I want to do some conditional formatting on messages that mention me.  Below are 3 sample Messages (Bodies).  The first two should be purple, the last one should not be purple because I don't want it to evaluate true for message chain headers (replies).

**Mention** *(should match query, does)*

> Hey Scott, can you...

**Mention in a message I had been involved in** *(should match query, DOES NOT)*

> Scott, did you say...
>
> fwded message sent from Scott Beeson (sbeeson@somemail.com)

**No mention in a message I was involved in** *(should NOT match query, does not)*

> Thanks Tim
>
> fwded message sent from Scott Beeson (sbeeson@somemail.com)

I have enabled the query builder in office and here is what I have started, unfortunately it only matches the first example above.  So my question is, is there some regex or other magic I can use to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: For what reason did you add "doesn't contain" clause? In your third example there is no "Scott" text. Why you can't remove this exclusion?

Comment: There is "Scott" text.... or am I confused what you're saying?

Comment: Ah.. Sorry. Then maybe you'd want to include the trailing comma to the "contains" clause and remove "doesn't contain" clause?